# print.xtable only displays, doesn't save to disk

Tags: r, xtable

Is anyone else having this problem?

```
> d <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=6:10)
> print(d, type="html", file="d:/delete/test5.html")
  x  y
1 1  6
2 2  7
3 3  8
4 4  9
5 5 10
```

My R version is version 2.12.2 and xtable version is xtable_1.5-6.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You haven't created an `xtable` object, only a data frame. So `print` is running the appropriate method for a data frame which doesn't include the writing to file options. Try:

```
d <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=6:10)
x <- xtable(d)
print(x, type="html", file="d:/delete/test5.html")
```

More generally, if you want to write things to a file, you can try `cat`.

Comment: Thanks! It's these little things that kill me.